# Torsion free space and how to describe geometrically the torsion free condition?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

In a space with the torsion-free condition $$\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y})=\nabla \mathbf{x} \mathbf{Y}-\nabla_{\mathbf{Y}} \mathbf{X}-[\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}]=0 \implies \nabla \mathbf{x} \mathbf{Y}-\nabla_{\mathbf{Y}} \mathbf{X}= [\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}] $$

A friend of mine told me that the torsion deforms the parallelogram induced by the parallel transport of a tangent vector along a curve, but this point of view doesn't satisfy me because a question arises from it: the deformation is with respect to what?
I think I have an answer but correct me if am wrong: the deformation of the parallelogram is compared to one induced by a parallel transport with a vanishing torsion.

Besides that, I want to reinforce an idea I hope you can help me, so for me, a geometric description of the condition above is that: the comparison of the parallel transport of $Y$ along the curve induced by $X$ and the parallel transport of X along the curve induced by Y give rise to a new curve that is induced by the Lie bracket of $X$ and $Y$ that is $ [\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}]$.

So I hope you understand the mind-twisting that am experiencing now, Am literally trying to know or describe torsion when there is no torsion?

Thank you.

Comment: [What is torsion in differential geometry intuitively?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20493/what-is-torsion-in-differential-geometry-intuitively)

Comment: thank's for the link, I didn't know this community !!